# How to get a multiple files

Tags: java, command-line, args

I have lots of txt  files that are labeled as different years for example 1900.txt 1901.txt....2013.txt . My code will take the year that someone would enter into the command line and the .txt version of it. The problem it that I am trying to get all the files of the decade of the year that was entered on the command line. Example if I put 1986 in the command line I want it to get all the files of that decade, 1980.txt, 1981.txt... 1989.txt. but I don't know how i would get them.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String line = ""; // string var to hold entire line

if (args.length < 1)
    {
    System.out.println("\nYou forgot to put a Year on the command line.");
    System.out.println();
    System.exit(1);
    };
String inFile = args[0];  // file name off command line
String year = inFile;
```

Comment: Your data file set up is potentially brittle and maybe even dangerious, and your question sounds like it may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code" when the real solution is to use a different approach entirely. Why all the files? Why not one or two data files, that you change as needed?

Comment: Just a little nitpick: The first year of the decade of 1986 is 1981, not 1980. That still belongs to the decade before. A decade begins from January 1st, NNN1. This is because there is no "year zero". The first year is 1CE, and the one before it is 1BCE.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
int year = Integer.valueOf(line); // This assumes valid input of course...
int beginningOfDecade = year - (year % 10) // 1986 - 6 = 1980

for(int i = beginningOfDecade /*1980*/; i < beginningOfDecade + 10 /*1990*/; i++){
  bringFile(i);
}
```

Also need to consider what happens when year is already at the beginning of the decade (i.e. 1980).
Do you want the previous decade (1970-1980) or the current (1980-1990)?

In fact, you can use **RealSkeptic**'s comment properly define this.

Comment: Where are you getting bringFile from?

Comment: You're gonna have to write that one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting the remainder when dividing by 10.  Use (%) instead of (/).  That will return 198 for 1980-1989, so then just multiply by 10.

Answer (score 0):

Giver **directory path** to get the List of files from the directory
Here **5** used in the subString() as, **1986.txt** last 5 letters "**6.txt**" needs to chop off.

```html
public static final String directoryPath = "directory Path";
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        File file = new File( directoryPath );
        if ( !file.isDirectory() )
            return;

        Map< String, List< File >> fileMap = new HashMap< String, List< File >>();
        for ( File txtFile : file.listFiles() )
        {
            if ( txtFile.isDirectory() )
                continue;
            List< File > fileList = fileMap.get( txtFile.getName().substring( 0, txtFile.getName().length() - 5 ) );
            if ( fileList == null )
                fileList = new ArrayList< File >();
            fileList.add( txtFile );
        }

        //Write logic to get the year as input
        String input = "1986";
        List< File > files = fileMap.get( input.substring( 0, input.length() - 1 ) );
    }
```